# SBCL Ctrl-C on Windows

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

In SBCL on Windows, if a bug in my code causes an infinite loop, by default, control-C does nothing. I have to kill the entire console (by clicking X at the top right of the command prompt window).

Is there a way to get control-C to break out of the loop?

Comment: This seems not to be true, at least in the general case. When I execute `(loop)` in a SBCL 1.4.2 console on Windows 10, pressing `C-c` drops me in the debugger with a `SB-SYS:INTERACTIVE-INTERRUPT`. Are you sure your code does not have handlers installed that are ignoring the signals?

Comment: @rwallace are you using emacs & slime by any chance? If so it will want to type Ctrl-C twice in succession. `C-c C-c` in emacs parlance

Comment: @Baggers, he said he has to click the X at the top right of the *command prompt* window. That would be great, but he probably doesn't have slime.

Comment: @jlahd I definitely didn't install any handlers.

Comment: @rwallace which sbcl version, which Windows version?

Comment: @jlahd SBCL 1.4.2, Windows 7.